# CASE WHEN IS NULL

Tags: sql, isnull, case-when

I want to put the PlaceTypeId  = 18 in the column PlaceType.PlaceTypeId if is it null. I tried with this case null but it don't work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
SELECT DoctorsAddress.AddressId, DoctorsAddress.Address, PostalCode.Locality, 
  (CASE WHEN (PlaceType.PlaceTypeId IS NULL) THEN 18 ELSE    
   DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId END) AS TipoLocal, 
  (CASE WHEN (placeofvisitquery.placeofvisit IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE
   DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Schedule END) AS Schedule, 
  PostalCode.PostalCode, DoctorsAddress.DoctorId, 
  (CASE WHEN (placeofvisitquery.placeofvisit IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE 'X' END) AS teste
FROM  DoctorsAddress 
 INNER JOIN PlaceType ON DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId = PlaceType.PlaceTypeId
 INNER JOIN PostalCode ON DoctorsAddress.PostalCode = PostalCode.PostalCodeId 
 INNER JOIN DoctorEnterpriseDetails ON DoctorsAddress.DoctorId = DoctorEnterpriseDetails.DoctorId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DoctorRepresentative ON
   DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = DoctorRepresentative.EnterpriseId AND 
   DoctorsAddress.DoctorId = DoctorRepresentative.DoctorId AND                       
   DoctorsAddress.AddressId = DoctorRepresentative.placeofvisit 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN placeofvisitquery ON 
   DoctorsAddress.DoctorId = placeofvisitquery.DoctorId AND
   DoctorsAddress.AddressId = placeofvisitquery.placeofvisit
WHERE (DoctorsAddress.DoctorId = @param2) AND (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 26)
```

Comment: instead of case use coalesce(field value, value when null, value when null etc) example `coalesce(placeofvisitquery.placeofvisit, 18)`  however what you have seems like it should work ( at start of case is unnecessary, but it shouldn't harm your results.. are you getting an error or is it just not returning expected results?

Comment: @xQbert It just not returning the result , returns the entire row empty

Comment: Could it be that PlaceType will never be null, because you used `DoctorsAddress INNER JOIN PlaceType ON DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId = PlaceType.PlaceTypeId`; if you replace that with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you should get null values for PlaceTypeId (that will be evaluated in your `CASE...`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you used an `INNER JOIN` between `DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId` and `PlaceType.PlaceTypeId`, so that will join every row `with a value` (and that excludes nulls) in `DoctorsAddress` with every corresponding row from `PlaceType`.

So you never get any row that actually has `PlaceType.PlaceTypeId IS NULL`.
You can have these though if you replace

`INNER JOIN PlaceType ON DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId = PlaceType.PlaceTypeId`

with

`LEFT OUTER JOIN PlaceType ON DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId = PlaceType.PlaceTypeId`

Then (in case DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId is null) you will have the selected row from `DoctorsAddress`, but no corresponding row in `PlaceType` will be found, because `DoctorsAddress.PlaceTypeId IS NULL` and because you cannot compare against NULL, hence every member of `PlaceType` will also be `NULL`.